# Android project depending on a Java project

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, build, compilation

I have a normal Java library project, called "PeriodicLib2", and an Android app project, called PeriodicApp2. Both are Intelij-Idea projects. I'm not using any build system, only what Idea has build-in.

I want PeriodicApp2 to depend on PeriodicLib2. I don't want to build my library project and add is as a library jar file, because I'm changing the library's code really frequent, and I would like the Android project to automatically build the library. I got something similar working, a java project depending on another java project. But when an android project depending on a java project, I get compile-time errors. These are the steps I tried to get PeriodicApp2 to depend on PeriodicLib2:

1. In the Project Structure of PeriodicApp2, Add < Library < Java
   [image: Step 1]
2. Select the library
   [image: Step 2]
3. Press ok in the next 2 popups
   [image: Step 3 - a]
   [image: Step 3 - b]
4. Check if the module is added
   [image: Step 4]
5. Check if the library is added
   [image: Step 5]

I can import and use the classes in PeriodicLib2 according to the idea auto-completion, but when I compile, I get the following compile/build error:
[image: Error]

I have been searching on Google & asking on #java, but I couln't find any solution. How can I get an Android project to depend on a pure Java project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Library dependencies should be .jar files, if you want to add a dependency that consist of source code files, you can try to add it to your project as a module (import module), and add it as a module dependency to your PeriodicApp2 module.

Comment: Would that still syncronize with the original PeriodicLib2 project?

Comment: Yes, the module is basically a reference to the source code somewhere on the filesystem. So any changes to the source code in the module are picked up automatically (when you build).

Comment: I'll try that as soon as possible (tomorrow) and accept the answer.